# display highlighting with pysolr

Tags: python, html, xml, solr, pysolr

I have a solr doc that looks like this:

```
<response>
    <result>
    ...
    </result>
    <lst name="highlighting">
        <lst name="vda.a">
            <arr name="illusDesc">
                <str>
                    Four (possibly five) female <em>figures</em> huddle together in contracted postures. The two largest
                </str>
            </arr>
        </lst>
        <lst name="vda.b">
            <arr name="illusDesc">
                <str>
                   blah blah <em>figures</em> blha blah blha
                </str>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

How do I iterate through the highlighting element?

I have this in an html file:

```
    {% for result in results %}
                <ul>
                    <li>Id: <a href="#">{{ result.id }}</a></li>
                    <li>Illustration Description: {{ result.highlighting }}</li>                             
                </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

But of course it prints all the text under hightlighting. I want to iterate over it to print the illusDesc text for each returned object. 'results' is a pySolr Results object.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the solution??

Answer (score 1):

`results.docs` contains the Solr documents you are iterating over. `results.highlighting` contains the Solr highlighting. You can access the highlighting for a document by using its ID as a key in `results.highlighting`. E.g.:

```
results.highlighting[result['id']]['content']
```